# AWS EBS application timing out when changed to a single instance environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application running on Elastic Beanstalk in load balanced environment however when I changed the configuration to a "single instance" environment the application returns a 408 Request Timeout with every https browser request to the server (custom domain).

The environment health in my AWS console shows everything is running okay so I am baffled by what could be causing the problem. When I change the configuration back to 'load balanced' everything works fine again.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details? When exactly does `408 Request Timeout` occur? How do you test it?

Comment: The ```408 Request Timeout```  happens every single time I am trying to access the web app from the browser.

Comment: I mean, relevant details such as are you using http or https? Custom domain? Default EB domain?

Comment: I am using https requests with a custom domain

Comment: Without LB, how did you ensure https on your instance? Did you re-configured your nginx? How did you obtain new ssl certificate for your domain?

Comment: Only just realized the LB communicates with the instances using http by default unless it is configured. My app redirects all http requests to https which is resulting in the timing out since only my LB and not my instance is configured to handle https. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem. I will provide an answer to clairy why your app does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I change the configuration back to 'load balanced' everything works fine again.

Since you are using HTTPS with custom domain, when you switch to a single instance, the HTTPS functionality is lost. To make HTTPS work on a single instance, you need to obtained new SSL certificate (AWS ACM can't be used), and deploy it on your instance though re-configured Nginx:

- [How to Setup SSL(HTTPS) on Elastic Beanstalk Single Instance Environment](https://aws.plainenglish.io/setup-ssl-https-on-elastic-beanstalk-single-instance-environment-d748ea04437d?gi=aa947067b184)